# How to wire up a click event for a custom usercontrol button? Should I use CustomControl?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, custom-controls, mouseevent

I wanted to create a button that had an image and a textblock as content. So I went about looking for an answer and found a post (*[Reusable Custom Content for Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568883/reusable-custom-content-for-buttons)*) which told me to create a usercontrol.

I did this and it works great. I can set the image source and text through dependency properties. However, I am stuck as there is no click event for my control.

I did a little more digging and concluded that I probably need a CustomControl derived from Button. Is this correct? Or would it be better to wire up a click event to my UserControl?

Here's my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.Usercontrols.MyButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="40"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Button Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="tehImage" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                <TextBlock Name="tehText" Text="{Binding Text}"
                           Style="{DynamicResource ButtonText}" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

**Implementation**

```
<my:MyButton ImageSource="../Images/MainSyncButton.png" ImageWidth="141" Text="Synchronise" Click="btnSynchronise_Click" />
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest option would be to just make your UserControl expose a click event, and pass through your Button's click event.

In MyButton's xaml:

```
<Button Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="onButtonClick">
```

In MyButton's code:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Click;

void onButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Click != null)
    {
        this.Click(this, e);
    }
}
```

You can then leave your "implementation" code as-is.

Answer (score 3):

The answer really depends on what your goals are for the control. You may be able to get away with not creating a user or custom control if you can manipulate the data that you are binding to. If all you want to do is display a dynamic image and text, then you could create an ImageText object that contains two properties. You could then bind the default Button control's Content property to this object and use a DataTemplate to define the layout of the content.

If you cannot control the data type that you are binding to, or if you're really set on the idea of creating a control then I would recommend creating a custom control. Custom controls allow you to utilize the built-in capabilities of a standard button. Generally you would only want to create a User Control if you wanted to hide or encapsulate the default functionality of the visual controls contained within the control.

Good luck.

Comment: Also a good suggestion, however i am going to stick with the UserControl this time as to just to get to grips with it. But thanks for clearing some things up for me.